# OTP auto detect not working in Firebase Phone Number Authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I followed the steps to integrate phone number authentication from [google's official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth). Earlier, otp auto detection used to work almost all the time, hence user did not need to enter otp manually, making login flow an ease. But recently after entering the phone number, everything works as expected except auto detect. So user now has to open messages app, check the otp, and enter it manually, making login a longer process. Tried to find the same issue on internet and [firebase github issues](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues), but no success. Is no one having this issue? Is otp auto detect deprecated? Am I missing something while implementing firebase authentication?

Thank you